# Laravel V8.83 + livewirehow can I inform the frontend while running long methods on backend

Tags: laravel

I've got some long running methods on my laravel application - some run about 8 minutes. How can I, in Laravel 8 and Livewire 2, setup up an information system which shows a little flash window that e.g. "Step x is done" and Step y is now running?

example:

```
 `public function updateData()
{
    $this->updateStatus = 'x wird aktualisiert...';
    sleep(2);
    $this->updateStatus = 'y wird aktualisiert...';
    sleep(2);
    $this->updateStatus = 'Alle Daten wurden aktualisiert.';
}`
```

Livewire never shows me the updateStatus message... :(
Where is the best point to start learning about this?

Thank you!

Stev

Ps: also tried to put the above example into pieces: and also didn't work as expected .. after 14 seconds I see only the finished text thats it...

```
 public function updateData()
{
    $this->updateStatus = 'x wird aktualisiert...';
    $this->render();
    sleep(2);
    $this->updateData2();

}

protected function updateData2(){
    $this->updateStatus = 'y wird aktualisiert...';
    $this->render();
    sleep(2);
    $this->updateData3();
}

protected function updateData3(){
        sleep(10);
    $this->updateStatus = 'Alle Daten wurden aktualisiert.';
    $this->render();
}
```

Comment: Update answer may be this time it is more clear

Comment: You probably want Laravel Echo broadcasts and a queued job for this. https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/laravel-echo

Comment: hey ceejayoz, I've read right now about jobs and queues but the problem is that I need the method run and finished and then go on - if it is not finished I can't allow the user to go on ... (checking with a com object if a usb device on the server is running as expected, if not the user can't go on and has to do some other checks) ... :( So it would be great if I can call my Method in anyway and show a loading text ... which tells the user whats checked on the usb device and if this check was successful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Livewire has good support with alpinejs.

Use Livewire in AlpineJs with $wire

`$wire.someMethod(someParam).then(result => { ... })`

or you can use

`let foo = await $wire.someMethod(someParam)`

For more check this https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js

Instead of using `wire:click="updateData"` you ahould use

```xml
<button x-on:click="$wire.updateData().then(() => {message = "done"})">update</button>
<span x-text="message">Content...</span>
```

Also here we run in javascript via alpinejs with $wire and run function sequential with using then then and then .Running updateData() that run other function can't do here.

You should do something like this

```xml
<button x-on:click="$wire.step1().
  then(() => {message = 'first done'; $wire.step2().
  then(()=> {message = 'first done';$wire.step3()})})">
  update
</button>
<span x-text="message">Content...</span>
```

Comment: HI Puneet Sharma, thanks for your reply I've tried this: 
in my Livewire blade: 
 `<div x-data="{ message: @entangle('updateStatus') }">
        <button wire:click="updateData">update</button>
        <span x-text="message">
        Content...
    </span>
    </div>`
and the above example in my component - I only see the message when its finished. 
Isn't this the same when I use .then(... and await ?

Comment: yeah tried it right now and the result is the same I don't see the messages :( only the last one that everything is finished :(, I think I didn't understand what's going on under the hood ???

Comment: Hell yeah! it works! and makes totally sense :) Thank you very much @Puneet Sharma

Answer (score 1):

for @ll coming here having the same question and for me :):
in your bladefile of your livewire component:

```
  <div id="app">
        <span x-text="message">         Content...     </span>
        <div x-data="{ message: @entangle('updateStatus') }">
            <button @click="$wire.updateData().then(() =>
    {$wire.updateData2().then(()=> {
       });})"> try me
            </button>

        </div>
    </div>
```

and in your component:

```
  public function updateData()
{
    $this->updateStatus = 'x wird aktualisiert...';

    sleep(2);


}

public function updateData2(){
    $this->updateStatus = 'y wird aktualisiert...';
           sleep(2);

}
```